# Accordion Collapsible Panel is Not Exanding After Adding Schema Markup

Tags: html, css, accordion

My accordion collapsible panel is working perfectly. As you can see, the first panel is not working, whereas the second one isn't working perfectly. The difference between these two is not something major. I have added schema markup in the first panel, but after that, it's not expanding over click. I want the panel to be expandable along with the schema markup and need help with that.

```css
.servive-info {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #ebf6f5;
  border: 1px solid #dae9f3;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #333333d9 !important;
}

.servive-info p {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.faqtitle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  border: none;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

.accordion .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.accordion label {
  display: block;
}

.accordion {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 15px 0px 8px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
  border: 0px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-top: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #004287;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.accordion .handle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-left: 2px solid #c82333;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.accordion label {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.accordion label:hover,
.accordion label:focus {
  background: none;
}

.accordion .handle label:before {
  content: '';
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
  border-color: #FBBC05;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.handle label:before {
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.accordion:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="servive-info" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage">
  <div class="accordion">
    <input type="checkbox" name="collapse1" id="handle1" checked="checked">
    <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
      <h2 class="handle" itemprop="name">
        <label for="handle1">1. What is your name?</label>
      </h2>
      <div itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
        <div class="content" itemprop="text">
          <p>My name is Adam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle2">
    <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
      <h2 class="handle" itemprop="name">
        <label for="handle2">2. What's your hobby?</label>
      </h2>
      <div class="content" itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
        <p itemprop="text">Playing outdoor sports.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You going to use that schema map on all accordian pieces?

Comment: Yes, I will use it on all questions and answers.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique so you want no matter how many div you add with scheme they should work. right? please check this and let me know if this helps. https://jsfiddle.net/kfcam79g/

Comment: @Leothelion The blue border is no longer working with that.

Comment: @ezw oh.. checking that and will update fiddle if user will give response as seems he got the answer.

Comment: @ezw, Thanks you so much for your efforts, I got the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding that schema map broke the accordian because it put the `div.content` in a different scope than what the CSS selector that is supposed to be targeting it.

Specifically, the following two CSS selectors/definitions.

```css
.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
    padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
    border: 0px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #004287;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

It is looking for a `div.content` that is a sibling to the input checkbox, and it is in the second accordion... but in the first accordion it isn't because it's in a scope of a different div element. Changing those two CSS selectors to the following

```css
.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~div>.content {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~div>.content {
    padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
    border: 0px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #004287;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Fixes your issue. Notice the added `div>` in front of `.content`. Updates the selector to grab the `div.content` in the updated HTML structure.

**UPDATE** With your updated HTML structure that you've changed to after this answer, just move that `.content` class designation one div up.

```css
.servive-info {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #ebf6f5;
    border: 1px solid #dae9f3;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #333333d9 !important;
}
.servive-info p {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.faqtitle {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 15px 0;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    border: none;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100vw;
}

.accordion .content {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~div>.content {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.accordion label {
    display: block;
}

.accordion {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 15px 0px 8px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~div>.content {
    padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
    border: 0px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #004287;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.accordion .handle {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    border-left: 2px solid #c82333;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.accordion label {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.accordion label:hover,
.accordion label:focus {
    background: none;
}

.accordion .handle label:before {
    content: '';
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
    border-color: #FBBC05;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~div>.handle label:before {
    content: "";
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.accordion:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="servive-info" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage">
    <div class="servive-info" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage">
        <div class="accordion" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="collapse1" id="handle1" checked="checked">
            
            <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                <h2 class="handle" itemprop="name">
                      <label for="handle1">1. What is your name?</label>
                </h2>
                
                <div class="content" itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                    <div itemprop="text">
                        <p >My name is Adam.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
            
        <div class="accordion" >                  
            <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle2">
            
            <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                <h2 class="handle" itemprop="name">
                      <label for="handle2">2. What's your hobby?</label>  
                </h2>
                
                <div class="content" itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                    <div itemprop="text">
                        <p>Playing outdoor sports.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable time and efforts that you have given in order to resolve my code issue. I really appreciate it. And once again thank you.

Comment: If it solves your issue, feel free to accept the answer

Comment: sorry to bother you but need one more help need to add one more div tag before content div.

Comment: Example:

 <div class="accordion" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle1" checked="checked">
        
        <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
            <h2 class="handle" itemprop="name">
                  <label for="handle1">1. What is your name?</label>
            </h2>
            
 <div itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
            <div class="content" itemprop="text">
                <p>My name is Adam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: I am updating the code please have a look.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique I've updated the answer to your question. Just move that `content` class to the previous `div` element, and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle1" checked="checked">
  <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question"> // *** just remove this div **** <h2 class="handle" itemprop="name">
      <label for="handle1">1. What is your name?</label>
    </h2>
    <div class="content" itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
      <p itemprop="text">My name is Adam.</p>
    </div>
  </div> // **** end of div ****
</div>
```

When styling the **handle** class in css, you used **.accordion .handle**, which says (an element with the handle class that exists in the accordion class), but **there is a **div** between these two elements (.accordion ), which prevents styling the handle class.**

### debuged code:

```css
/* Accordion Collapsible Panel Starts */

.servive-info {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #ebf6f5;
  border: 1px solid #dae9f3;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #333333d9 !important;
}

.servive-info p {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.faqtitle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  border: none;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

.accordion .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.accordion label {
  display: block;
}

.accordion {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 15px 0px 8px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
  border: 0px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-top: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #004287;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.accordion .handle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-left: 2px solid #c82333;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.accordion label {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.accordion label:hover,
.accordion label:focus {
  background: none;
}

.accordion .handle label:before {
  content: '';
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
  border-color: #FBBC05;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.handle label:before {
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.accordion:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/* Accordian Collapsible Panel Ends */
```

```html
<div class="servive-info" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage">
  <div class="accordion">
    <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle1">
    <h2 class="handle" itemprop="name">
      <label for="handle1">1. What is your name?</label>
    </h2>
    <div class="content" itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
      <p itemprop="text">My name is Adam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle2">
    <h2 class="handle">
      <label for="handle2">2. What's your hobby?</label>
    </h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Playing outdoor sports.</p>.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am updating the code please have a look.

Comment: Do you even read the question. You removed the scheme div which user wants to have. This is not what user asked.